# jar file conflicts in maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, urlclassloader

Right now I am using a *maven project*. And this project uses some `logging.1.jar`. There is a new functionality which we are going to add to this project and is dependent on `logging.3.jar`.

The compilation is fine, but the application is failing at runtime due to jar file conflict.

Reason is the newly added functionality, it is using `logging.1.jar` instead of `logging.3.jar`

I cannot initialize a class which is present is newly added functionality as it dependent on `logging.3.jar`. How can it be resolved?

Will it be resolved using `URLClassLoader`?

Comment: Delete the jar files and re-run maven dependency download?

Comment: Maybe if you provide your pom it is easier to answer. Have you already checked maven exclusion?

Comment: @pirho Here there are 2 different versions of same jar file. For new functionality to work, I need to initialize a class which is dependent on higher version(new) jar file. But at runtime it is always looking for lower version jar(existing jar). I have to work with 2 jar files. How can I resolve this.

Comment: _But at runtime it is always looking for lower version jar(existing jar)_. So is it doing it so by some explicit code or by some special classloader? I guess you have logging3.jar as dependency also?

Comment: @pirho,  No. If I add logging.3.jar, the existing code fails due to compilation error. How can I resolve this...

Comment: _The compilation is fine, but the application is failing at runtime_ & _the existing code fails due to compilation error_. Please update your question first to clarify your problem better. Add the compilation & the runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add proper jar dependency into your pom.xml and run mvn clean-install -U command. this command clean your discrepancies and update correctly.

Answer (score 0):

See part **Dependency Exclusions** on [Maven introduction](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html).

So you should have to something like this in your pom:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.examle</groupId>
      <artifactId>including-jar</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>org.logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>logging</artifactId> (or logging1)
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
```

The tricky part is that you must find the artifact(s) ( including-jar(s)) that are dependent on the old version and add this exclusion to all of those artifacts.

On the other hand it is also possible to prevent this older artifact to be actually *loaded* by setting its scope as provided, like:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.examle</groupId>
      <artifactId>logging</artifactId> // or logging1
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
```

However this latter solution might not suit all situations and I personally prefer the first because it does not obfuscate the real purpose (so excluding) and will not cause surprises later.